# How to create filter

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have a database table with multiple columns

I use custom List<> and populate it from database
What i want to do is filter what will go into the list from database depending on user input

for example if i had a table like this:

```
name|phone|date|address
```

User can specify any filter(by name, by phone, by date... or all of it) and only items that matches all criteria will go into the list

Is there a way to do this?

Method that returns all items from database

```
public List<MoviesDatabaseEntry> getAllMovies(String table)
{
    List<MoviesDatabaseEntry> lists = new ArrayList<MoviesDatabaseEntry>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + table;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            MoviesDatabaseEntry list = new MoviesDatabaseEntry();
            list.set_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            list.set_title(cursor.getString(1));
            list.set_runtime(cursor.getString(2));
            list.set_rating(cursor.getDouble(3));
            list.set_genres(cursor.getString(4));
            list.set_type(cursor.getString(5));
            list.set_lang(cursor.getString(6));
            list.set_poster(cursor.getString(7));
            list.set_url(cursor.getString(8));
            list.set_director(cursor.getString(9));
            list.set_actors(cursor.getString(10));
            list.set_plot(cursor.getString(11));
            list.set_year(cursor.getInt(12));
            list.set_country(cursor.getString(13));
            list.set_date(cursor.getInt(14));


            // Adding  to list
            lists.add(list);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return list
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return lists;
}
```

Comment: certainly, but your question is lacking important detail. What database are you using and how does your database query code look?

Comment: sqlite in android, what do you mean database query. I have a method for retrieving items from database. Is that what you mean?

Comment: When you are using sqlite you certainly have an SQL query ("SELECT * FROM table;") somewhere. Or are you using some framework to access the database? Please add the code which accesses the database to your question.

Comment: updated question with that method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the entries you get in the SQL query you are building in this line:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + table;
```

To filter the dataset your retrieve, you would add a WHERE clause to it. When you would, for example, only want those entries where the rating is over 3, you would change this to:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + table + " WHERE rating > 3";
```

SQL is a very powerful language which offers a lot of possibilities. It's an essential skill when you work with relational databases. When you want to learn it, I can recommend you the interactive tutorial website http://sqlzoo.net/

Comment: OK, what about multiple filters?

Comment: you just add next condition in where clause ... where column1 > 1 and column2 = 'somestring' ...

Comment: @pedja Please don't be a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/). I showed you a website which teaches you fishing, so stop asking for more fish.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your database query for getting specific data from the query.

You have one function that returns all rows from database like so: `getAllMovies(String table)`

Here you are using:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + table;
```

Make a new function like this:

```
public List<MoviesDatabaseEntry> getSelectedMovies(String table)
{
    List<MoviesDatabaseEntry> lists = new ArrayList<MoviesDatabaseEntry>();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] { <your row names> }, 
                **check condition(as string)**, null,
                null, null, null, null);
    ...
}
```

Now just call this function when required with your specific query string

Make as many functions as you want!